# Using Unity 4.6.1// Which Facebook SDK Should I Use?

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am using Unity 4.6.1(Latest Version) and now planning to integrate Facebook SDK to my new game. However, I am confused with the version of Facebook SDK when I read topics about problems of FB SDK 6.1 with Unity 4.6.1. Should I use FB SDK 6 instead 6.1?

Comment: check out this link it may help : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Unity4.6.1 as well and used Facebook SDK 6.0.
The only change which I was supposed to do was to change the FB.cs file.
Change required:

```
#if UNITY_4_5
  ...code
#end_if
```

To

```
#if UNITY_4_6
   ....code
#end_if
```